# How Can I use generated sequence within composite primary: Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I am using a sequence generator within composite primary keys,What is the correct format to use it?
I have an org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException when I  persist two objects.

Thanks in advance.

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EXT_TB_TITULAR")
public class ExtTbTitular implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@EmbeddedId
private ExtTbTitularPK id;

@Column(name="CTITU_NOMB")
private String ctituNomb;

public ExtTbTitular() {
}

public ExtTbTitularPK getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(ExtTbTitularPK id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCtituNomb() {
    return this.ctituNomb;
}

public void setCtituNomb(String ctituNomb) {
    this.ctituNomb = ctituNomb;
}
}
```

**Composite  Class:**

```
   @Embeddable
   public class ExtTbTitularPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long ntituCodigo;

    private long numeSecue;

    private long solicitudId;

    public ExtTbTitularPK() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "entity_titular")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "entity_titular", sequenceName = "SEQ_EXT_TB_TITULAR",                                allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "NTITU_CODIGO", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public long getNtituCodigo() {
        return this.ntituCodigo;
    }
    //ETC..............
```

**Method**

```
   ExtTbTitulartitular titular = new ExtTbTitular();
   ExtTbTitularPK id = new ExtTbTitularPK(); 
   titular.setId(id);
   titular.getId().setSolicitudId(bean.getSolicitud().getSolicitudId());
   titular.getId().setNumeSecue(bean.getNumeSecue);
   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(titular);
```